# Go GORM Preload & Select only items matching on preload table condition

Tags: go, go-gorm

Im trying to use GORM to select only items from the parent table that have a matching condition in a related table.

```
type Table1 struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Email string
    Items Table2
}

type Table2 struct {
    gorm.Model
    Product string
    otherfield string
}
```

I want to return all Table1 items that have Product in Table2 set to a specific value. So far I am getting mssql: The multi-part identifier "visits.sign_out_time" could not be bound. a lot.

My command is

```
var items []Table2
db.Debug().Preload("Table2").Where("table2.product = ?", "xxx").Find(&items).GetErrors()
```

Not entirely sure where I'm going wrong but for whatever reason the .Where() cannot access the second, preloaded table. How do I go about using GORM to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Where("table2.product = ?", "xxx")` cannot access the second (preloaded) table because `Preload` is not a `JOINS`, it's a separate `SELECT` query. Your code creates two separate queries, something like this:

```
// first query
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table2.product = 'xxx';
// second query
SELECT * FROM table2;
```

In order to return all `Table1` records that have `Product` in `Table2` set to a specific value you have to do the following:

```
var t1 []Table1
err = db.
Where(`EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.product = ? AND table1.id = t2.table1_id)`, productValue).
Find(&t1).Error
```

Note that `AND table1.id = t2.table1_id` part is just an example how the two tables might be related, you may have a different relation and you'll need to modify the query accordingly.

If you want GORM to populate the `t1.Items` with the `Table2` data, you prepend `Preload("Items")` to the above query.

Comment: Thanks @Anton - Although not intuitive it works. Not sure I like GORM as much as say EF but once I learn the ins and outs perhaps it will grow on me.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want only `Items`, you can directly query on `Table2` no need to preload `Table1`

```
var items []Table2
db.Where("product = ?", "xxx").Find(&items).GetErrors()
```

Or you need all data of `Table1` then Join with `table2` then use where clause

```
db.Debug().Joins("JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id")
          .Where("table2.product = ?", "xxxx").Find(&table1data)
```

Here I don't see any foreign key in `Table2` for join.You can add one.

```
type Table2 struct {
    gorm.Model
    Product  string
    Table1ID uint
}
```